# Debugging ASP.NET on a built-in web server suddenly stops

Tags: asp.net, debugging, cassini

I have Windows Server 2008 (64-bit), VS 2008 with its built-in webserver and an ASP.NET MVC 1.0 webapp.

All I'm trying to do is to debug said app. I have a bunch of breakpoints, but they behave in a very strange way. When I fist start a debugging session with F5 and hit a breakpoint, the debugger stops just fine. However, after several F10s/F11s debugging suddenly "stops" (no exceptions at that time), but neither VS detaches from browsers' process, nor webapp execution stops: Visual Studio stays attached, and web request continues executing as usual.

I tried various browsers (Chrome, Firefox, IE), but to no avail.

What do I do to solve this? It really drives me insane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it figured. There was a background thread running in a webapp, and it whenever it happened to throw an exception (which was not caught), debugging session would stop.

Comment: yep, multiple threads + debugging + cassini = gnashing of teeth and rending of hair.

Answer (score 1):

You could stop using F5 and use Debug -> Attach to Process instead. I have found that this gets rid of some of the debugging attachment issues that I have had.