# Cannot Debug in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010

I am suddenly unable to debug in VS. I am developing an MVC app. I made no changes whatsoever to application settings. I simply modified a property in a class like I've done many of times.

I am getting the popup

> Debugging Not Enabled
>
> This page cannot be run in debug mode because debugging is not enabled in the Web.config file. What would you like to do?
>
> (.)Modify the Web.config file to enable debugging.
>
> ( )Run without debugging.

I have compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" in my Web.Config file. Clearly debugging is enabled. I've restarted VS, rebooted, but same thing.

When I say immediately, I mean from one debug session, to another within about 10 minutes. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: see this might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061679/debugging-asp-net-suddenly-stops

Comment: Nope. That was about debugging stopping during a debug session. I cannot even get debugging to start. Option is set to debug, not release as suggested in the article as well.

Comment: You need to make sure your web.config file contains:
<compilation debug="true" defaultLanguage="c#" />
Depending on what your default language is of course.

Answer (score 1):

Copying somebody else's fix to your question, see if that helps:

Fixed this by registering/installing ASP.NET 4.0

c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i

If you're using 32 bit change Framework64 to Framework. 
Link is [Unable to start debugging on the web server](http://www.visualwebgui.com/Developers/Forums/tabid/364/forumid/27/threadid/46210/scope/posts/Default.aspx)

Try see if it works

Comment: Wow, it really solved my Problem!! :-) Thank you soo much! +1