# Entity Framework with sections

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am creating this EF select and breaking down into small section. I can see the listOfFFee filled with data. But when add the Larger EF section visual studio debugger stops. I dont get any errors and the data is not returned. Is there anything I can do because I am lost without an error.

//smaller EF section using list

```
var listOfFFee = (from p in db.Pricings
                    select new
                    {
                    p.Id,
                    p.Price,
                    })
                    .ToList();
```

//Larger EF section

```
FlatFee = listOfFFee.Where(f => f.Id== p.id
                Select(s => s.Price.HasValue ? s.Price.Value : 0)
                .FirstOrDefault(),
```

Comment: Well the second code block wouldn't compile. Might be a typo, but you're missing a `)` and `.` between the `Where` and the `Select`

Comment: For the VS debugging stopping issue, check that you are set to break on all exceptions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3062055/5803406

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you break it into 2 or more subsections to maybe see where the problem is, and wrap in `try...catch`? eg:

```
try{
  var FlatFeeA = listOfFFee.Where(f => f.Id== p.id).ToList();
  var FlatFeeB = FlatFeeA.Select(s => s.Price.HasValue ? s.Price.Value : 0);
  var FlatFeeC = FlatFeeB.FirstOrDefault();
}
catch (Exception e){
  var xx = 10; // put breakpoint here to examine 'e'
}
```

Comment: Thanks this helped the error is `"Unable to create a constant value of type 'Anonymous type'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context."}`

Comment: which step is throwing that error? Where are you trying to create a constant?

Comment: I trying to set decimal? but I getting `Anonymous type'.error` Do I need to  cast the int in the `.Where f => f.Id== p.id`

Comment: I didn't look at your overall logic when I wrote my reply - I was just giving you advice on running down your problem. What type is `listOfFee.Id`? what is `p`? `ListOfFee` is an anonymous type, but I don't see where you're trying to create a constant. You could consider making a POCO class to represent `ListOfFee`, or just use the full db object in the query.

Comment: Yeah I do the full db object in the query but then its is harder to read and understand If I do the use the POCO object then I get the error `CLR type to EDM type is ambiguous because multiple`.

Comment: listOfFee.Id is an id  and I an just selecting one of the object in the collection.

Comment: 'id' is not a type.... Please look at all my questions (they end with a question mark) and answer them, then I will be better able to help you

Comment: Sorry my mistake it an int `?listOfFFee [0].Id.GetType()
{Name = "Int32" FullName = "System.Int32"}`

Comment: `p` is the System.Data.Entity.DbSet for the table

Comment: Well, if `p` is a `dbset`, it's not going to have an `id`. Each *row* will have an `id`, but the set as a whole will not. So this: `var FlatFeeA = listOfFFee.Where(f => f.Id== p.id).ToList();` cannot work. I think you're going to have to create a minimal, reproducible example and update your question or ask another one: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score -1):

Could you try this ? I hope it would work.

```
FlatFee = listOfFFee.Where(f => f.Id== p.id)   
                    .FirstOrDefault()
                    .Select(s => s.Price.HasValue ? s.Price.Value : 0);
```

Comment: OP says "I dont get any errors and the data is not returned". It's unclear how this would fix that since this would technically fix a build error, and they would never even have gotten to the point where "the data is not returned"

Comment: `FirstOrDefault` will return one instance or `null`, so unless a single record is *also* enumerable, `Select` won't work in that position of the expression. *Plus* `Select` will throw `ArgumentNullException` if `FirstOrDefault` returns `null` (i.e. no records that match the condition).

Comment: Would a try and catch help in anyway? Will I see more information?